# Triggering action if user canceled touch on mobile device

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, mobile-safari, jquery-events

I have a situation where I need to track if a user has cancelled a touch on a mobile device. I thought it would be pretty easy with touch events, but I've been stuck on it for two days now. Here's what I've been experimenting with:

```
$("#element)
  .bind('touchstart', function() {
    action1();
  })
  .bind('touchcancel', function() {
    action2();
  })
  .bind('touchend', function() {
    action3();
  })
```

`touchstart` and `touchend` work fine, but `touchcancel` never runs. Even if I release my finger outside the element, the `touchend` action will run but not `touchcancel`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried dragging your finger off the edge of the display panel? That used to cause a touchcancel on older android phones.

Edit: The touchcancel happens when the system needs to cancel the touch so you might experiment with application- or OS-initiated behavior that could interrupt what the user is doing. Some examples that might cause this

- Receive an onscreen notification, like an incoming call
- Modify the dom so the element that was the focus of the touchstart is rerendered in a different location
- Remove the dom element that was the focus of the touchstart

Comment: I have.. did not make a difference :(

Comment: I just read your edit, and I gotta say that just smells funky. Do you know of any ways to detect a user intended cancel other than mapping the positions?